# Failed to start Gunicorn

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn

Trying to deploy django app on ubuntu.

start-server.sh has

```
cd /home/django
source env/bin/activate
cd tutorial
gunicorn tutorial.wsgi
```

If I bash start-server.sh everything runs perfectly fine.

So, I wrote following thing.

gunicorn.service saved at /etc/systemd/system/ looks like

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=django
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/django/bin/start-server.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then I run

```
 sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
 sudo systemctl start gunicorn
```

but now I see 502 error. when I bash start-server.sh, everything was perfect. but, somehow with gunicorn its not working.

guincorn version 18.0(I tried 20.0 but no luck)

sudo systemctl status gunicorn shows

```
● gunicorn.service - Gunicorn
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-06-09 16:56:59 UTC; 2min 5s ago
   Main PID: 26285 (code=exited, status=126)

Jun 09 16:56:58 ip-184-168-120-14.ip.secureserver.net systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
Jun 09 16:56:58 ip-184-168-120-14.ip.secureserver.net systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 09 16:56:59 ip-184-168-120-14.ip.secureserver.net systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 09 16:56:59 ip-184-168-120-14.ip.secureserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped Gunicorn.
Jun 09 16:56:59 ip-184-168-120-14.ip.secureserver.net systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 09 16:56:59 ip-184-168-120-14.ip.secureserver.net systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 09 16:56:59 ip-184-168-120-14.ip.secureserver.net systemd[1]: Failed to start Gunicorn.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following line on top of `start-server.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This is called the "shebang" line. Unixlike systems typically don't pay attention to the file extension, so the fact that the filename ends in `.sh` is ignored. It is this line that the system looks in order to determine that the file is going to be executed by bash.

In addition, you need to ensure the file is executable:

```
chown +x /home/django/bin/start-server.sh
```

However, you really don't need `start-server.sh` at all, because everything it does can be done by systemd. Add this line to the `[Service]` section:

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/django/tutorial
```

and replace `ExecStart` with this:

```
ExecStart=/home/django/env/bin/gunicorn tutorial.wsgi
```

That's all. If you find it confusing, read [virtualenv demystified](https://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/).

Comment: #!/bin/bash 

Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the `cd`-commands in you bash-script and use fullpaths instead

```
source /home/django/env/bin/activate
gunicorn /home/django/env/bin/activate/tutorial.wsgi
```

Comment: shows /bin/bash: /home/django/bin/start-server.sh: Permission denied
Tried sudo chown myuser /home/django/bin/start-server.sh -R
But no luck